# How to create Oracle 19C Database SQL Developer New Connection?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

Well I am a college student and I have a database project to build on Oracle 19c (SQL Developer) just like a management system. When I click on new connection in SQl Developer , then enter database name (my project name) and enter user name as system and pswd. and is SID I write 'orclpdb' and when I connect it gives an error that database is not open. How can I start making tables and stuff and complete my project on oracle 19c sql developer. Please guide me.
Update: While creating new database connection in SQL Developer, In Service name if I write 'orcl' and test then the connection is successful but when I write 'orclpdb' it says 'database not open'

Comment: You'll need a database. SQL Developer is a tool which lets you access it (the database). According to the error you got, it looks that you DO have it. But, did you start it up? If on MS Windows, check Services and start Oracle and TNS Listener.

Comment: Please guide how can I check TNS listener?

Comment: It seems you are at the very beginning of the problem. Do you have some tutorials or other materials in your college. If not, there is a lot of information about the process in Oracle web site. For example, you can model and create the database using a virtual machine (already full configured from scratch). See, e.g., https://www.oracle.com/es/database/technologies/appdev/datamodeler.html

Comment: For testing the listener: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/connect.htm#NETAG357

Comment: Our instructor didn't teach us at all about listener and virtual machine and stuff. He just taught us how to download oracle 19c and SQL developer and then unlock HR database and then create new connection from within SQl developer and he just taught us about orcl and orclpdb.

Comment: While creating new database connection in SQL Developer, In Service name if I write 'orcl' and test then the connection is successful but when I write 'orclpdb' it says 'database not open'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it sound like the container database (orcl) is started but the pluggable database (orclpdb) is not.  You need to start it.

In order to actually manage a database you are going to have to learn to work without SQL Developer, and use the command-line utility sqlplus.

From a command line:

```
C:> set ORACLE_SID=orcl
C:> sqlplus / as sysdba   
SQL>  alter pluggable database orclpdb open;
```

In the above, the sqlplus command is launching the command line utility 'sqlplus'.  the '/' indicates to make a local connection to the database specified by the env variable ORACLE_SID, using OS authentication (os user is a member of the ORACLE_DBA group), and connect with 'sysdba' authority.  On the next line the 'SQL>' is just indicating you are now at the sql prompt within sqlplus, you actually enter the 'alter' command, whose purpose should be self-evident.

The listener is a totally separate process. It is like a telephone switchboard.  It 'listens' (hence, its name) for connection requests coming across the network, and set up the connection, then is out of the picture.  You check its status at the command line:

```
C:> lsnrctl status
```

One last bit of useful (for us) information.  What this the connection 'type' you've defined in SQL Dev?  Is it 'basic' or 'tns'?  Either way, what did you specify for the values?  Please name the field(s) AND the value you supplied.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the valuable help. I managed to create the connection. Now the issue is, Whenever I restart my laptop and resume working on my project in SQL developer, I always have to open the database 'orclpdb' from SQL Plus. Is there any way to keep that open? Also am I working the correct way, for example I am creating a database for a school management system, then is it the right way to use connection type as basic, username as system, hostname: localhost, port: 1521, Service name: orclpdb.

Comment: As for starting the pdb automatically, I could explain but as a student you need to learn to research.  What did you find when you googled "automatically start oracle pdb when cdb is started"?  Hint: oracle-base.com is very good at providing 'cookbook' solutions.  As for "is this the right way to use connection", .... if it works, then it is the right way.  The choice between 'tns' and 'basic' in SQL Dev is mostly personal.  With 'basic', you provide the necessary addressing info directly.  With 'tns' you refer to an entry in your tnsnames.ora file which, in turn, provides the addressing info.

Comment: Additional background about oracle tns (network) connections... several articles that explain common connection errors, thus giving good overall background, at https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/category/tns/